# iOS Swift Combine: cancel a Set<AnyCancellable>

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine, anycancellable

If I have stored a cancellable set into a ViewController:

```
private var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()
```

Which contains multiple subscription.

1 - Should I cancel subscription in deinit?  or it does the job automatically?

2 - If so, how can I cancel all the stored subscriptions?

```
bag.removeAll() is enough?
```

or should I iterate through the set and cancel all subscription one by one?

```
for sub in bag {
   sub.cancel()
}
```

Apple says that the subscription is alive until the stored AnyCancellable is in memory. So I guess that deallocating the cancellables with `bag.removeAll()` should be enough, isn't it?

Answer (score 41):

On `deinit` your ViewController will be removed from memory. All of its instance variables will be deallocated.

The docs for `Combine > Publisher > assign(to:on:)` say:

> An AnyCancellable instance. Call cancel() on this instance when you no
>   longer want the publisher to automatically assign the property.
>   Deinitializing this instance will also cancel automatic assignment.

**1 - Should I cancel subscription in deinit? or it does the job automatically?**

You don't need to, it does the job automatically. When your ViewController gets deallocated, the instance variable `bag` will also be deallocated. As there is no more reference to your `AnyCancellable`'s, the assignment will end.

**2 - If so, how can I cancel all the stored subscriptions?**

Not so.  But often you might have some subscriptions that you want to start and stop on, say, `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidDissapear`, for example. In this case your ViewController is still in memory.

So, in `viewDidDissappear`, you can do `bag.removeAll()` as you suspected. This will remove the references and stop the assigning.

Here is some code you can run to see `.removeAll()` in action:

```
var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func testRemoveAll() {
  Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    .sink { print("===== timer: \($0)") }
    .store(in: &bag)

  Timer.publish(every: 10, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    .sink { _ in self.bag.removeAll() }
    .store(in: &bag)
}
```

The first timer will fire every one second and print out a line.  The second timer will fire after 10 seconds and then call `bag.removeAll()`. Then both timer publishers will be stopped.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3235801-assign

Answer (score 23):

if you happened to subscribe to a publisher from your View controller, likely you will capture `self` in `sink`, which will make a reference to it, and won't let ARC remove your view controller later if the subscriber didn't finish, so it's, **advisable** to weakly capture self

---

so instead of:

```
   ["title"]
      .publisher
      .sink { (publishedValue) in
        self.title.text = publishedValue
    }

.store(in: &cancellable)
```

you should use a `[weak self]`:

```
   ["title"]
      .publisher
      .sink { [weak self] (publishedValue) in
        self?.title.text = publishedValue
    }

.store(in: &cancellable)
```

thus, when View controller is removed, you won't have any retain cycle or memory leaks.

Comment: how does this answers his question though?

Comment: @giorashc  user asked if he should cancel subscriptions manually or "it does the job automatically", my answer shows how you can avoid thinking about subscriptions if there's no any strong references to self. by using this way, subscriptions will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 14):

Try creating a pipeline and *not* storing the cancellable in some state variable. You’ll find that the pipeline stops as soon as it encounters an async operation. That’s because the Cancellable was cleaned up by ARC and it was thus automatically cancelled. So you don’t need to call cancel on a pipeline if you release all references to it.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable):

> An AnyCancellable instance automatically calls cancel() when deinitialized.

Comment: it does not seem to work this way as documentation say. I tested syncRequest().sink().store(in: &disposables) and defined it on viewmodel and add deinit { } to view model. deinit prints each time switching screens but subscription receiveCancel is not call and receiveValue is called multiple times

Comment: @MichałZiobro sounds like a good question for stackoverflow :D

Comment: `subscriptions.removeAll()` works fine in Swift 5.4

Answer (score 10):

I test this code

```
let cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()

Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
  .sink { print("===== timer: \($0)") }
  .store(in: &cancellable)
  
cancellable.removeAll() // just remove from Set. not cancellable.cancel()
```

---

so I use this extension.

```
import Combine

typealias CancelBag = Set<AnyCancellable>

extension CancelBag {
  mutating func cancelAll() {
    forEach { $0.cancel() }
    removeAll()
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean "just remove from set" vs "array"

Comment: This isn't correct at least for now on IOS 17.4 Simulator and Xcode 15.3. Not sure relative swift version.
If `removeAll()` then sink closure won't be called.

Answer (score 3):

**Create a Cancellable+Extensions.swift**

```
import Combine

typealias DisposeBag = Set<AnyCancellable>

extension DisposeBag {
    mutating func dispose() {
        forEach { $0.cancel() }
        removeAll()
    }
}
```

In your implementation class, in my case `CurrentWeatherViewModel.swift` simply add `disposables.dispose()` to remove `Set` of `AnyCancellable`

```
import Combine
import Foundation

final class CurrentWeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var dataSource: CurrentWeatherDTO?

    let city: String
    private let weatherFetcher: WeatherFetchable
    private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(city: String, weatherFetcher: WeatherFetchable = WeatherNetworking()) {
        self.weatherFetcher = weatherFetcher
        self.city = city
    }

    func refresh() {
        disposables.dispose()

        weatherFetcher
            .currentWeatherForecast(forCity: city)
            .map(CurrentWeatherDTO.init)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] value in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                switch value {
                case .failure:
                    self.dataSource = nil
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
                }, receiveValue: { [weak self] weather in
                    guard let self = self else { return }
                    self.dataSource = weather
            })
            .store(in: &disposables)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you explicitly call `cancel` for each `AnyCancelable` in the set? Just calling `removeAll()` is enough to set them nil and cancel the ongoing subscriber tasks.

Comment: You shouldn't use publishers like this and manually dispose it. You should make use of a publisher and then put your `weatherFetcher` in a `flatMap` and put it in your `init`

Comment: can't import combine .    its not in scope ?

Comment: Are you suggesting creating a different dispose bag for an additional subscription as you are cancelling on refresh?